# How to batch process a PHP script that takes a long time to execute?

Tags: php, batch-processing, execution-time

I've built a PHP script that creates/restores a backup containing a sites content and database. It works really well on smaller sites but it runs into trouble on larger sites. What would be the best way to batch a script like this? Basically, it copies files from one directory to another, creates a DB dump and then zips the directory.

I've done a little bit of research, do I need to use cron jobs?

Comment: Can you break it into smaller segments? Are you trying to run it via a web page? Otherwise, CRON would work nicely and you wouldn't have to worry about the time (to a point).

Comment: Is this on a Windows or Linux server?

Comment: Trying to run it via a webpage. The user clicks 'Backup', the script creates a backup.

Comment: Dev server is Windows, live server is Linux. I'd prefer it to work in both environments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is something that happens at a fixed time / schedule, then it should be a cron job. This is fairly straightforward to set up. There are plenty of tutorials.

If, on the other hand, it is an action a user triggers from a web browser, you should [fork](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) and [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php). You take in the user's input, fork and exec and then let the user know that he will be emailed when the process is complete.

Comment: Thanks, its the latter of the two. I'll look into it.